# Django and Pymongo connection not getting established

Tags: python, django, mongodb, python-3.5

I am running an application where I need to have connection between the MongoDB and the Django application.
I am running the application with the command:  `python manage.py runserver`

I am using `Python 3.5` on `windows 10 OS`

Here is my `settings.py` file part where I am trying to attempt the connectivity between the `MongoDB` and `Django`

```
from pymongo import MongoClient
# MONGO_DATABASE_NAME = 'testdb'
# MONGO_HOST = 'localhost'
# MONGO_PORT = 27017
MongoClient("mongodb://localhost:27017")


SESSION_ENGINE = 'mongoengine.django.sessions'
SESSION_SERIALIZER = 'mongoengine.django.sessions.BSONSerializer'
```

The part where I am getting the connection error is :

```
if form.is_valid():
    # process the data in form.cleaned_data as required
    # ...
    # redirect to a new URL:
    # print (form.cleaned_data['for_analysis'])
    mongo = API_Mongo()
    mongo.content = form.cleaned_data['for_analysis']
    mongo.save()
    logger.debug('Text Data saved to Mongo DB')
    data = form.cleaned_data['for_analysis'].encode("utf-8")
```

The error occur at `mongo.save()`

The following is the error:

```
Exception Type: ConnectionError at /analyze/
Exception Value: You have not defined a default connection
```

My complete TraceBack is available here:  [TraceBack](https://gist.github.com/JafferWilson/18e3a941d9517cd522a96069d56654aa)